# ECharts Pie Chart disappears when put inside flex container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, echarts

[This demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rgppqu?file=src%2Fecharts.component.ts,src%2Fmain.ts) renders an EChart Pie Chart renders fine when it is outside a flex container.  This is the markup.

```
<div style="height: 200px;" echarts (chartInit)="onChartInit($event)" [autoResize]="false" [options]="options"></div>
```

When the demo is put inside a `flex` container like this, the chart gets zero width and disappears.

```
<div style="display:flex;">
       <div style="height: 200px;" echarts (chartInit)="onChartInit($event)" [autoResize]="false" [options]="options"></div>
  </div>
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: The [documentation](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echarts.init) states that the init function should get a "a DIV element with height and width defined"

Comment: Yeah I think it has nothing to do with Echarts. Its just that a normal div uses the full width by default and in a flexbox the content inside is fit. Since you initially pass an empty div it has a width of 0. You can test that behaviour by using an empty div with a different background-color than the flex container.